# Configuring DNS Server on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, hostname, ptr-record

I am a newbie at Windows Server Management and am trying to host a website on my Windows 2012 VPS

I have installed IIS, added the site and the site is up and running. The domain is from GoDaddy and I have used Godaddy's DNS zone file to point the site to the public IP address of my server.

However, when I am trying to setup the DNS server and adding hosts and PTR records, they are not resolving to their corresponding values.

After adding hosts and PTR records, when I do a nslookup, I get the following

```
C:\>nslookup
Default Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222
```

OpenDNS is being used in the Network Adapter as the Preferred DNS server.

When I enter mail and prag1 which are respective hostnames, I get the following

```
> mail
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

*** resolver1.opendns.com can't find mail: Non-existent domain
> prag1
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

*** resolver1.opendns.com can't find prag1: Non-existent domain
```

When I check the IP for the PTR record, I get

```
> 1.2.3.4
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa
        primary name server = localhost
        responsible mail addr = nobody.invalid
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 600 (10 mins)
        retry   = 1200 (20 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 10800 (3 hours)
*** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available
 for 1.2.3.4
```

** 1.2.3.4 - Local IP

Please advise where I might be going wrong here. I have watched several videos on YouTube and I am doing exactly what they are showing but to no avail.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I condensed the discussion into an official answer.

Comment: `mail` and `prag1` aren't fully qualified domain names so naturally they can't be resolved by DNS. When using nslookup you should resolve the fully qualified domain name, such as `prag1.yourdomain.com.`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the comments into an official answer:

- You can't setup PTR records on your VPS. This needs to be done by the owner of the netblock (your VPS provider). He should offer some way to configure these.
- If your DNS is already hosted by a 3rd party provider (GoDaddy in this case), there is no need to setup forward records and you shouldn't do it without experience in running DNS services. You would need to point the zone to your own DNS servers in that case, but really, don't.
- Running mail services for "mail campaigns" is really difficult and as a beginner, you have very little chance of doing this successfully even in the best circumstances. Using a professional service provider is really your best bet for this.